# Javascript toLocaleString doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, date

I wrote the following code:

```
console.log(
(new Date(Date.now())).toLocaleString('fr-FR', {weekday: "short", year: "numeric", month: "short", day: "numeric"}));
```

Result is:

```
2017 M05 9, Tue
```

I was waiting for something like:

```
mar. 9 mai 2017
```

"mar." is the short version of tuesday and "mai" is for may.

Someone could tell me how to get the result I was expecting ?

Comment: I got your expected output from Firefox and Chrome.  Where is your code running?

Comment: In a heroku instance in the log window. I then use the result in a notification sent through OneSignal (and display result is different on phones)... Would you know a better way to manipulate dates in different languages?

Comment: So you're running in Node.js? You may need to install or update language packages; I don't know how that works in Heroku.

Comment: Support for the ECMA-402 Internationalisation specification is fairly poor, and it still leaves a lot up to implementations to interpret and have differences over, so don't expect any particular result or the output from different implementations to be the same. For the record, Safari gives "mer. 10 mai 2017".